# JSON Output from serialization is not working as expected

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I;m using jackson jar to get the String to Object using serialization concept. I'm trying to create sample json for learning purpose.. every thing is working fine but the only thing i'm getting the same field twice. can you please help me to solve this thing.

***Student class with fields***

```
public class Student {

    private String StudentName;
    private int RollNo;
    private int Total;
    
    public String getStudentName() {
        return StudentName;
    }
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        StudentName = studentName;
    }
    public int getRollNo() {
        return RollNo;
    }
    public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
        RollNo = rollNo;
    }
    public int getTotal() {
        return Total;
    }
    public void setTotal(int total) {
        Total = total;
    }
    
}
```

***School Class which will accept the student class data***

```
public class School {

    Student student;
    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }
    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

}
```

***Serialization Class which generates the JSON***

```
public class JSONMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
       Student std=new Student();
       std.setStudentName("Satish");
       std.setRollNo(10);
       std.setTotal(350);
       School scl=new School();
       scl.setStudent(std);
       ObjectMapper obj=new ObjectMapper();
       obj.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
      String text=obj.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(scl);
      System.out.println(text);
    }

}
```

***Output in  console***

```
{
  "student" : {
    "StudentName" : "Satish",
    "RollNo" : 10,
    "Total" : 350,
    "studentName" : "Satish",
    "total" : 350,
    "rollNo" : 10
  }
}
```

don't know why it is giving StudentName, studentName and remaining fields twice with same values.

Comment: Rename your fields like _StudentName_ -> _studentName_ getter and field doesn't match so comes twice

Comment: You are setting `Visibility.ANY`. this will also serialize private fields.

Comment: i understood but what if i don't want to rename it.. because is there any naming convention for the json...

Comment: @derpirscher, what i can change the visibility from ANY..

Comment: But there is a naming convention for java about field name like _studentName_ which followed when serialize

Comment: Ok EkLavya,, your solution is working for me.. upvoting to your ans.

Comment: as @Eklavya-UpvoteDon'tSayThanks said, you should update your property names. If you are curious though, check here how it works https://dzone.com/articles/jackson-property-custom-naming-strategy

Comment: For instance `NONE_PRIVATE` or `PUBLIC_ONLY`. For details check the documentation.